If ($M_t$) is a L2-bounded martingale then $M_t^2$ is uniformly integrable.
I am stuck at the end of the proof:
The martingale ($M_t$) is u.i. by Hölder and $M_t = \mathbb{E}[M_\infty|F_t]$. Using Fatou's lemma, we obtain that the random variable $M_\infty$ is square integrable and with Jensen's inequality:
$$  M_t^2 \leq \mathbb{E}[M_\infty^2 | F_t]$$
Then using conditional expection's properties, I derive:
$$\mathbb{E}[M_t^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{M_t^2>K\}}] \leq  \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M_\infty^2 | F_t] \mathbb{1}_{\{M_t^2>K\}}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M_\infty^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{M_t^2>K\}}| F_t] ] =\mathbb{E}[M_\infty^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{M_t^2>K\}}]   $$
Let $\epsilon >0$. Using that $M_t \underset{t\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}  M_\infty$ a.s. there exists $T>0$ such that:
$$\forall t > T, \mathbb{P}(|M_t^2 - M_\infty^2| > 1 ) \leq \epsilon $$
Then $\forall t > T$,
$$\mathbb{E}[M_\infty^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{M_t^2>K\}}]  = \mathbb{E}[M_\infty^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{M_t^2>K+1\}} \mathbb{1}_{\{|M_t^2 - M_\infty^2|<1\}}]  + \mathbb{E}[M_\infty^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{M_t^2>K\}} \mathbb{1}_{\{|M_t^2 - M_\infty^2|>1\}}]  \\
\leq \mathbb{E}[M_\infty^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{M_\infty^2>K+1\}}] + \mathbb{E}[M_\infty^2 \mathbb{1}_{\{|M_t^2 - M_\infty^2|>1\}}] $$
I find myself stuck with the right member. Could you please indicate me how to conclude?
Best.

The result from one of Doob's martingale inequalities, which gives a bound on the integral of $X = \sup_t M_t^2$ for $M \in L^2$. The integrability of $X$ implies that $(M_t^2)$ is UI. Here is a reference.

You can also use the fact that the martingale $Y_t:=\Bbb E[M_\infty^2\mid\mathcal F_t]$ is uniformly integrable, and $0\le M_t^2\le Y_t$ for all $t$ (by Jensen).
Same reasoning works for an $L^p$-bounded martingale, for any $p>1$.

How do you derive that $Y_t$ is uniformly integrable? Otherwise it is indeed much shorter, thank you.

It’s the conditional expectations of a single integrable random variable.

Here is a detailed proof using J.S. comment (there might be shorter):
The martingale ($M_t$) is u.i. by Hölder and $M_t = \mathbb{E}[M_\infty|F_t]$. Using Fatou's lemma, we obtain that the random variable $M_\infty$ is square integrable.
Since $\mathbb{E}[M_\infty^2] < +\infty$, Doob’s maximal inequalities yield
$\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t}M_t^2] \leq 4 \mathbb{E}[M_\infty^2]  < +\infty  $.
The random variable $\sup_{t}M_t^2$ is therefore integrable.
Define $Y_K := \sup_{t} \mathbb{1}_{\{M_t^2 > K\}} M_t^2$ (it is non negative)

$\forall K > 0, Y_K \leq \sup_{t}M_t^2$ which is integrable.
$Y_K \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\longrightarrow} 0$.
Let $\epsilon >0$. Observe that for $K>\epsilon$, $\mathbb{P}(Y_K > \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(Y_K >K) \leq \mathbb{P}(\sup_{t}M_t^2 >K)$.
Since $\mathbb{E}[ \sup_{t}M_t^2] < + \infty$, Markov inequality yields :

$$ \mathbb{P}(\sup_{t}M_t^2 >K) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[ \sup_{t}M_t^2] }{K}  \underset{K \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 $$
Using Lebesgue's Dominated convergence theorem
$$\lim_{K \to +\infty} \int Y_K d\mathbb{P} =  \int 0 d\mathbb{P} = 0  $$
Hence
$$ \lim_{K \to +\infty} \sup_t \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{M_t^2 > K\}} M_t^2] \leq \lim_{K \to +\infty} \mathbb{E} [\sup_{t} \mathbb{1}_{\{M_t^2 > K\}} M_t^2] = 0$$
Therefore $(M_t^2)$ is uniformly integrable.
